# REference for SCORM 2004 data model

Tags: scorm, scorm2004

Where do I find the SCORM 2004 run time data model details?Looking for pdf which explains each data model in detail. Any reference?

Comment: Got it http://www.adlnet.gov/Technologies/scorm/SCORMSDocuments/2004%204th%20Edition/Documentation.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the best one I've found:
http://www.scorm.com/wp-content/assets/scorm_ref_poster/RusticiSCORMPoster-large.pdf

Answer (score 2):

There is also an online reference chart that can be a bit easier on the eyes and contains accurate information for all of the SCORM versions and editions available at http://www.scorm.com/scorm-explained/technical-scorm/run-time/run-time-reference/

Comment: Thanks Mike. Scorm.com is like dictionary / reference book/online tutorial for me for all my SCORM needs. I infact learnt SCORM from scorm.com. When I posted the question, I was looking for explanation on whats objective in cmi.objectives and stuf..

Answer (score 1):

The official SCORM 2004 documentation is available on the ADL website. It includes detailed descriptions of the data model. http://www.adlnet.gov/Technologies/scorm/SCORMSDocuments/2004%204th%20Edition/Documentation.aspx